# Glob import returns empty module in Parcel

Tags: javascript, parceljs

I use Parcel for its speed but I have a little problem. The Glob resolver just ignores the folder content.

I need import all content from folder `/documents` which contains PDF & HTML files. So I tried:

```
import * Docs from "url:/documents/*.{html,pdf}"
```

But it does not work and in source map, there is a file `/documents/*.js`:

```
module.exports = {}
```

---

.parcelrc

```json
{
    "extends": "@parcel/config-default",
    "resolvers": [
        "@parcel/resolver-glob", 
        "..."
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real problem why parcel returned `{}` was [Scope Hoisting](https://parceljs.org/features/scope-hoisting/). I wanted to access dynamically:

```
import * as Docs from "url:./documents/*.{html,pdf}";

const embeds = Object.values(Docs).map(src => (
    <iframe src={src} className="document" />
));
```

So the solution is turn off scope hoisting via `--no-scope-hoist`

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to change `/documents` to `./documents`, and add an "as" keyword, so the full import is:

```
import * as Docs from "url:./documents/*.{html,pdf}"
```

Internally, `@parcel/resolver-glob` uses [isGlob](https://www.npmjs.com/package/is-glob) to test whether the string is a valid glob, and exits silently if it is not. It would probably be a better error experience if it gave you some sort of feedback about the error ¯_(ツ)_/¯

Here's [an example project where glob imports are working correctly](https://github.com/astegmaier/parcel-documents-glob).